# What is the connotation of "up" in phrases like "eat up" and "wait up"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases, colloquial-language, connotations

What do you feel "up" in "eat up" and "wait up" indicates? Does it sound like "be quick" (eat up) or "I'll be quick" (wait up)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connotation is *completion*.

"Wait up!" means "wait *a sufficient time* for me to catch up".

If you eat something up, you don't just take a bite of it, you consume it entirely.

Comment: I would say "wait up" means "don't go to bed until..."

Comment: It can mean that too.   But my example has an exclamation point, and is thus in the imperative voice.

Comment: I was going to edit, but then decided that *up* in your usage might not denote completion but the opposite of "down", i.e. not asleep. *I will wait up for you. Don't come home too late.*

Comment: Heh! I almost upvoted the first single sentence answer. The edit was confusion. Your last comment was better: completion.